# Logic error in Actionscript Code

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have the following logic in my code

```
if((leftCombo.getSelectedIndex() !> rightCombo.getSelectedIndex())&&(rightCombo.getSelectedIndex() !< leftCombo.getSelectedIndex())
```

Doing something wrong obviously.

Here are the errors

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 112 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before not.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 112 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before logicaland.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 112 1084: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before not.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!> and !< are not valid operators....

This is easily seen by your error traces:

```
Syntax error: expecting rightparen before not.
```

The not operator (!) is found, next to an invalid token (<) and the error arises.

What are you trying to say?

Assuming !> means "not greater than", then you should use <=
Assuming !< means "not less than", then you should use >=

Answer (score 0):

There are no `!>` and `!<` operators. What do you expect them to be? Is `!>` supposed to be *not bigger than*? If that’s the case, just use `<=` and `>=` then (i.e. *not bigger than* is equal to *lower or equal to*).

Also note that if that’s the case then you can get rid of one of those cases, i.e. you would be checking `a <= b && b >= a` where one of those two would be completely redundant.